# Possible to update PK to a composite PK in SQL Server without destroying the table relations?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, primary-key

Hi I got an existing table and due circumstances I need to edit my PK to a composite PK.
How can I update my current table PK PARTYID.

Some info:

I want PARTYID & PARTYGUID to become my composite PK.

[image]

Is this possible without destroying it's relations with other tables?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not at all.
You will have to remove all dependencies, change the PK and then add the dependencies back with the new field on the FK.

For example, the tblPartyParty will need a PARTYGUID field too

Comment: Mmm, this is what I not hoped for, but thnx!